# Expanding Series with a OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following characteristics:

```
            tag_id
object_id   
    1           77
    2           77
    3           91
    4           91
    5           91
    6           91
    7           77
    8           91
    9           85
    10          88
    10          211
    11          100
    12          81
    12          91
    13          65
    14          73
    15          91
    16          174
    17          91
    18          62
    19          62
    20          91
    ...         ...
    1527        105
    1527        108
    1528        87
    1529        91

    1907 rows × 1 columns
```

As you can see, some of the index values actually do repeat with a different "tag_id" value. I want to re-organize this DataFrame with OneHotEncoder to transform it into a sparse matrix with binary values, like so below:

```
            1    2    3    ...    77    ...    85    ...    88    ...    91    ...    211
object_id
    1       0    0    0    ...    1     ...    0     ...     0    ...    0     ...     0
    2       0    0    0    ...    1     ...    0     ...     0    ...    0     ...     0
    3       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     0    ...    1     ...     0
    4       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     0    ...    1     ...     0
    5       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     0    ...    1     ...     0
    6       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     0    ...    1     ...     0
    7       0    0    0    ...    1     ...    0     ...     0    ...    0     ...     0
    8       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     0    ...    1     ...     0
    9       0    0    0    ...    0     ...    1     ...     0    ...    0     ...     0
    10      0    0    0    ...    0     ...    0     ...     1    ...    0     ...     1
```

etc. etc.

Using pd.get_dummies(df['tag_id']) gives me somewhat what I want, but it does not stack rows with repeated index, so I end up with 1907 rows still, rather than 1907 - number of repetitions.

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to `sum`

```
pd.get_dummies(df['tag_id']).sum(level=0).ne(0).astype(int)
```

Or drop the duplicate

```
pd.get_dummies(df['tag_id'].groupby(level=0).first())
```

Comment: Neat solution mate, really like this one liner. Thank you! I have also found an alternative solution myself - will add it in the original question body.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wen-Ben's excellent answer, I have found an alternative one:

```
# Definition of categories (df_str is a master list of all possible 'tag_id' values)
cat = [int(x) for x in sorted(df_str['id'].unique())]

# Definition of data
data = df.groupby(df.index).agg(list)
data = data['tag_id'].apply(lambda row: [int(el) for el in row])

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = cat).fit(data)
encoded_data = mlb.transform(data)

df_tags_encoded = pd.DataFrame(data = encoded_data, index = data.index, columns = ["tag_id_" + str(name) for name in cat])
df_tags_encoded.head(10)

        57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  ...     203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212
object_id                                                                                   
    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0

10 rows × 156 columns
```